# different alignments for different columns and items

Tags: wpf, listview, alignment

Got a WPF app.

it uses a listview control.

I have 3 columns.
I want the 1st column header to be left aligned
I want the other 2 to be centred aligned
I want one the items to be right aligned (just so I know how to do it).

With my markup everything is Left aligned so what am I doing wrong?

This is my markup:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="value1Template">
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="value2Template">
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding Path=IncludesVATCaption}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="value3Template">
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding Path=Cost}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

<ListView x:Name="lvWorkItems">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" CellTemplate="{StaticResource value1Template}"  Width="190">
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="IsVat" Width="50" CellTemplate="{StaticResource value2Template}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Cost" Width="65" CellTemplate="{StaticResource value3Template}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saw that behaviour cause you set style for `GridViewColumnHeader` and it is applied for all columns. You can change this `Style` by adding `DataTrigger` for `Center` alignment columns.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Column.HeaderStringFormat}" Value="Center">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And you should set `HeaderStringFormat="Center"` property for them. I know it's a little tricky.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="IsVat" Width="50" CellTemplate="{StaticResource value2Template}" HeaderStringFormat="Center"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Cost" Width="65" CellTemplate="{StaticResource value3Template}" HeaderStringFormat="Center" />
```

Comment: well done.It is all a bit 'wiry' and this is my 1st WPF app but the results at the end makes it all worth while - especially when compared to WinForms

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `HorizontalContentAligment` property to `Stretch` so that the column/cell inside a row can take the required space. This can be achieved by setting the property through `ItemContainerStyle`.

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
       </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for that. I partially worked.  Items were all OK but the 2nd and 3rd column were also aligned to the left and want them to be centered?